# Moving Data from Table to Table with new Column

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to move some data which relates to a specific column from one table to another. They both have a matching objectID.

So what I am trying to do is:

```
TABLE 1 
ObjectID
Field with Data

TABLE 2
ObjectID
FIELD with NEW column
```

So the object ID relate to each other. All it is I am trying to do is move the data from Table 1 to Table 2 with the new column.

I have tried following but cant seem to get it all working. Is there anything that can be suggested that may help or point in me the right direction.

```
 update Table2  a
   Set a.NewColumn = (Select *
                     From Table1 b WHERE a.OBJECTID = b.OBJECTID
                     )
```

Comment: Are you trying to move data from only one field from table1 to table2 `new_column` ?

Comment: Yes only from one column.  The Tables will remain but it needs to relate to the OBJECTID. So Currently in Table with new field created is empty, this needs to be populated by relating to the objectid. Both tables have the same objectID

Answer (score 0):

Hm, maybe I don't get it but why don't you use a INSERT?

```
INSERT INTO TableB(...columns...)
SELECT ...columns...
FROM TableA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join update` syntax for this, need to make sure that the `Table2` already has data and you are updating a new column in there from `Table1`

```
update Table2 t2
join Table1 t1 on t1.OBJECTID = t2.OBJECTID
set t2.NewColumn = t1.Field
```

Comment: This sounds like what I am after, I have tried this but not working. Will try a few things, see if I can get it working.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide some sample data and the actual table definitions. It could be tested on http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 0):

You can write query like this.

```
INSERT INTO Table2(ObjectID,Field)
SELECT ObjectID,Field
FROM Table1.
```

And you can put any default value in extra column.